# Tricks to pass from a ostringstream to a istringstream

Tags: c++, converters, stringstream, streambuf

I try to make a module of compression/decompression and then use istringstream for compression and ostringstream for decompression.

My problem is that after filling my istringstream with compression datas, I'm not able to convert this stream into an ostringstream. I try :

> iss.rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());

as the in and out type match but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: You may want to just use a stringstream rather than an ostringstream and an istringstream, as you can read and write from/to it: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/basic_stringstream/

Comment: Note that doing this is very risky as any input operations on `iss` will affect `oss`'s buffer. You won't find any changes in `iss` reflecting `oss`. This is simply one among other potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringstream::rdbuf` doesn't have an overload that takes a parameter. It does, however, inherit the base class version which does have this property:

```
iss.basic_ios<char>::rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());
```

The fact that you couldn't use it originally is because the derived class version hides it.